# Reading hexadecimal data into byte array in Java?

Tags: java, stream, arrays, hex

I'm reading data from an SNES ROM using Java. I am opening a stream and reading in the bytes into an array:

```
InputStream stream = open("foo.rom");
final int startingSize = stream.available();
byte[] data = new byte[startingSize];
final int numberRead = stream.read(data, 0, startingSize);
```

In the ROM, I have this value:

**E4 2B 00 02 03 00 FF 3A 00 83**

228 43 0 2 3 0 255 58 0 131 (in decimal)

However, my code is behaving weirdly. After setting up some debug statements, I have this pattern when printing with String.valueOf(data[ref]):

**-28 43 0 2 3 0 -1 58 0 -125**

(This address in the ROM is the first where data appears, but I am noticing incorrect values elsewhere in the program.)

As near as I can tell my Java byte array is not respecting the hexadecimal data. How can I set my byte array to do so?

Comment: There is a specific warning in the Javadoc against using `available()` in exactly the way you're using it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java treats all bytes as being signed, so they can only be in the range -128 to +127. The bit pattern `E4` corresponds to -28 in two's complement.

You can convert signed bytes to pretend-unsigned-ints by doing something like `String.valueOf(data[ref] & 0x00FF)`. That will strip off the sign bit and auto-convert to an int.

Comment: But then what am I to do? Replace the references of "byte" with "int," convert the data, and hope for the best?

Comment: No, only do the conversion for debugging. You probably want to keep the raw data as it is for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a function to print out each byte in the more well-known zero-padded hex string format:

```
public static String toHexString(byte b) {
    return String.format("%02X", b);
}
```

(Yes I know there are more efficient ways to write this method.)

Answer (score 1):

It's working perfectly fine. Keep in mind that `byte` is a signed type, so a value greater or equal than 128 is interpreted as `256 - value`.

Comment: No it isn't. It is interpreted as `value-256`.