# Java UDP hex data split by delimiter?

Tags: java, split, udp, hex

I'm receiving hex data via UDP protocol, and I want to split data into pieces.

For example (captured with wireshark):

> FF 6D 53 74 69 **00** 6B 1A 30 31 2D **00** 3A 65 65 2F 64

As you can see the delimiter is 00.

I want to separate the split data into multiple pieces. What am I supposed to do? Do I need to convert into a string or...?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129835/reading-hexadecimal-data-into-byte-array-in-java

Comment: You are receiving the data as `byte`s -- scan left to right looking for zeros and split them.  Try writing some code to do this and then if you still have trouble, post a question showing what you've written.